# Can the square that ends a proof (similar to QED) be considered to claim the same thing as "necessarily" from modal logic?

Tags: logic, modal-logic

I've only thought of this because superficially they look the same, and seem to be making similar claims. When you prove a statement P=>Q ◻, then is it the same as writing ◻P=>Q in modal logic?

Comment: No; it is only a way to signify the end of the proof. It seems it is due to Halmos (see [here](http://jeff560.tripod.com/set.html)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Mauro indicates the original intention of Halmos was not ◻ to mean "necessarily". But if you agree that our logic holds in all possible worlds - a necessary assumption when discussing possible worlds at all - then any mathematical(!) proof A => B holds necessarily in any possible world, hence ◻(A=>B).